How to export a variable in Mathematica to .mat format such that MATLAB loads the file, the data is imported to something not called Expression1
Hopefully this is a simple problem.
When I export, in mathematica, saving the variable:
linearArrayVariable

to a file on disk called
"myfile"

using the command:
Export["myfile", linearArrayVariable];

And then I load it into Matlab with the load command:
load("myfile.mat")

I get a 1x1 structure called Expression1. I can easily fix this my immediately assigning a new variable name by saying:
linearArrayVariable=Expression1;

But this is sort of a pain, especially when I have several variable to import that were saved.
Thanks!

It is hidden in export options in this page MAT.html

SO you need to export with custom name

There does not seem to be other options shown on this page. i.e. need to give some name else Expression1  is used by default.
